# How can I access property of base class from subclass

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two classes:

- Base class is `player` it has property `name`
- Sub class is `computer`

How can I set the name of the computer player by accessing the base class property?

base class

```
@interface Player : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString* playerName;
@property (nonatomic) int score;

-(id) initWithName :(NSString*) playerName;
-(void) addScore:(int) points;

@end
```

subclass

```
@interface Computer : Player

@end
```

.m

```
#import "Computer.h"

@implementation Computer

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name{
    self = [super init];
}

@end
```

Comment: I read and try alot of example nothing work

Comment: Unless you've done something strange, the answer is the same as if it was a property of the subclass itself.  If that's not working, we need details (code).

Comment: which examples did you try?... you can directly use 'self.name' in any subclass directly..

Comment: I add (self=[super init]) then self.name copiler say name is not property of computer

Comment: @PhillipMills i add code pls help

Comment: `Computer` should call `[super initWithName:name]` rather than `[super init]`.  Then `Player` can set its own `playerName`.

Comment: Where is `@property (nonatomic) NSString* playerName;` declared? Player.h? or Player.m?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to make out so please let me know if I've answered something other than what you are asking.

Assuming you have a class, car, that has inherited from a super class, vehicle, and that vehicle has an attribute, wheels, you can get at that in this way:

```
super.wheels = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the property in the `Computer` Class like

```
super.name = @"Bob";
```

You can also call the methods of the superClass with

```
super.myMethod();
```

Comment: doesn't work the subclass doesn't see the super class as player

Comment: What exactly did you do? Where did you create the player? Sure it is a subclass?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the property from the superclass in the subclass directly.

Player.h

```
@interface Player : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

Computer.h

```
@interface Computer : Player
@end
```

Computer.m

```
@implementation Computer

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
  self = [super initWithName:name];
  if (self) {
    self.name = @"test";
  } 
  return self;
}

@end
```

Although, as @Phillip Mills suggested, it's probably better practice to set the name property in Player.m instead.